# Python and Beautiful Soup nested values

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following html:
    `<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rMon_3"> <span>12 M <span>+300 €</span></span> </label>`

How can I get the 12 M and +300 €?

**Edit:**
So I tried this to get alle the data I need, but find just picks the first value.

```
vObj_detail = bsObj.find('label', attrs={'class': 'cOpt'}).get_text(strip=True).split("+")
```

The original source looks like this, so there are more then one.

```
[<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rMon_0">
<span>6 M</span>
</label>

<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rMon_1">
<span>24 M
<span>+150 €
</span>
</span>
</label>

<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rMon_2">
<span>18 M
<span>
+200 €
</span>
</span>
</label>

<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rMon_3">
<span>12 M
<span>+300 €
</span>
</span>
</label>

<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rRen_0">
<span>1.250 km
</span>
</label>

<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rRen_1">
<span>1.750 km
<span>+100 €
</span>
</span>
</label>

<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rRen_2">
<span>2.000 km
<span>+150 €
</span>
</span>
</label>

<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rRen_3">
<span>2.500 km
<span>+250 €
</span>
</span>
</label>]
```

Thanks,
Sven

Getting 12 M and 300

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yesterday I was not able to add the whole source. But edit helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.get_text()` with `separator=` and then `str.split`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<label class="cOpt" for="prod_1234_rMon_3"> <span>12 M <span>+300 €</span></span> </label>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

a, b = soup.find("span").get_text(strip=True, separator="|").split("|")
print(a)
print(b)
```

Prints:

```
12 M
+300 €
```

---

Or: use `.find` and `.find_next`:

```
a = soup.find("span").find(text=True)
b = a.find_next(text=True)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Prints:

```
12 M 
+300 €
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. Helped me to go a step further.